# creating an object gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to js.
I am creating an object but somehow it dosen't give result in console.
here is my code.

```
var car=new object();
car.name="Mercedes Benz";
car.speed=220;
car.showNameAndSpeed=function(){
console.log("The name of the car is " + car.name + " and the topspeed is " + car.speed());
    };

car.showNameAndSpeed();
```

It says **object is not defined.** What am i doing wrong??Thanks.

Comment: `car.speed()` is incorrect.  `speed` is a property of the `car` object, it's not a function.

Comment: `var car=new Object();`

Comment: `var car = {};` does the trick (or use capital `O` in your code). Notice also, that `speed` is not a function.

Comment: Everyone Please enter the answer so i can upvote you.Thanks,.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that `object` needs to be capitalized - `object` isn't a thing in JavaScript, but `Object` is.

You want:

```
var car=new Object();
```

As [w3schools says](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp), JavaScript identifiers are case sensitive:

> All JavaScript identifiers are case sensitive.
>
> The variables `lastName` and `lastname`, are two different variables.

So `object` and `Object` are two different things, and you want `Object` - almost everything in JS starts as an `Object`.

[More on Object here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp).

---

Also, as ozil pointed out, you should change `car.speed()` to simply `car.speed`. You've previously set `car.speed` to `220`, so it's not a function. `car.speed()` tries to treat it as a function, which will cause issues.

---

So, in all, this code is what you want:

```
var car=new Object();
car.name="Mercedes Benz";
car.speed=220;
car.showNameAndSpeed=function(){
console.log("The name of the car is " + car.name + " and the topspeed is " + car.speed);
    };

car.showNameAndSpeed();
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way to create an object, in my opinion:

```
var car = {
    name: "Mercedes Benz",    
    speed: 220,
    showNameAndSpeed: function(){
        var self = this;
        console.log("The name of the car is " + self.name + " and the topspeed is " + self.speed);  
    }
}

car.showNameAndSpeed(); //Output: The name of the car is Mercedes Benz and the topspeed is 220
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vgy64L5r/)

Answer (score 0):

`object` needs to be capitalized and `car.speed()` needs to be `car.speed` as `speed is not a function`